# clear failed states (or all old logs) from systemctl status <service>?

Tags: centos, logs, systemctl

Tried different things but can not get this old entires removed cleared/. When I run

```
systemctl status httpd.service
```

Result:

```
Mar 09 09:28:08 il systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 09 09:28:08 il systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Mar 09 09:28:08 il systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Mar 09 09:28:08 il systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Mar 09 19:27:59 il systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 09 19:27:59 il systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

The **failed** state is shown in red, I would like to clear all old log entries.

Tried:

```
systemctl reset-failed 
systemctl reset-failed httpd.service
```

But it keeps showing up.

Running `CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done by clearing all the journal log:

```
sudo journalctl --rotate && sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=1s
```

or:

```
sudo rm /var/log/journal/*/*.journal
sudo systemctl restart systemd-journald
```

Comment: Thanks. the journalctl --rotate doesn't work ( unrecognized option '--rotate'), the second works does something, but when running "systemctl status httpd.service" it still shows the old failed status. Maybe because the rotate doesn't work?

Comment: @Roger See my edit, please.

Comment: thanks! that did it.